# Django admin template not found

Tags: django, django-admin

Suddenly django admin couldn't find login template.
When accessing /admin/ it raises `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

Strange thing is that it searches for `admin/login.html.html` that, obviously, does not exist in any of paths supplied.

Any idea where does it add the extra `.html`?

**EDIT:**

url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('dashboard.urls')),
)
```

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 80, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 58, in resolve_template
    return loader.get_template(template)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 146, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 139, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: admin/login.html.html
[04/Nov/2013 16:55:11] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 74150
```

Core is the module that contains settings.py, urls.py and models.py (core models, that are project-wide)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'core',
    'dashboard',
    'south',
)
```

Comment: do you maybe accidentaly created an app yourself that's also called `admin`?

Comment: Nope. I got an app called `dashboard` that handles its templates correctly.

Comment: Post your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `urls.py`

Comment: could you maybe post the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that coworkers had added middleware that should handle RESTful requests and messes with the template loader. So there was the problem.